# how to delegate struts2 action's instantiation to spring using annotations

Tags: java, spring, configuration, struts2, annotations

Hello I have a Struts2 application where struts actions were defined in the `struts.xml` file. Now, I want to delegate this to Spring in order to have actions with session scope.

- Case 1 : if I use Annotation `@Repository("myAction")` I always get the error : Unable to instantiate `Action`, `myAction`,  defined for `doAction` in namespace `/omb` `doAction`
- Case 2 : if I use the `applicationContext.xml`, I have a `NullPointerException` on `myService.callMethode();`

How can I do this using annotations? Because it will be too long to redefine all the services in the `applicationContext.xml`

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="do" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="com.omb.i18n.StrutsResourceBundle" />
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory" /> 
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire" value="name" />
    <constant name="struts.i18n.encoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
    <constant name="struts.i18n.reload" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.configuration.xml.reload" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.locale" value="fr" />
    <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="100000000000" />
    <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>

    <constant name="struts.codebehind.classSuffix" value="Controller"/>
    <constant name="struts.codebehind.action.checkImplementsAction" value="false"/>
    <constant name="struts.codebehind.action.checkAnnotation" value="false"/>
    <constant name="struts.codebehind.action.defaultMethodName" value="index"/>
    <constant name="struts.configuration.classpath.defaultParentPackage" value="rest-default" />

    <package name="default" extends="tiles-default" namespace="/">

        <interceptors>

            <interceptor name="params-filter"
                class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParameterFilterInterceptor" />

            <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="exception" />
                <interceptor-ref name="alias" />
                <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
                <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
                <interceptor-ref name="chain" />
                <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven" />
                <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                    <param name="maximumSize">11204928</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="staticParams" />
                <interceptor-ref name="conversionError" />
                <interceptor-ref name="params" />
                <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
                <interceptor-ref name="validation" />
                <interceptor-ref name="workflow" />
            </interceptor-stack>

        </interceptors>

        <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

        <global-results>
            <result name="technicalError" type="chain">
                errorAction
            </result>
            <result name="sessionInvalidError" type="tiles">
                sessionInvalid
            </result>
            <result name="blank" type="tiles">blank</result>
        </global-results>

        <global-exception-mappings>
            <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception"
                result="technicalError" />
            <exception-mapping
                exception="com.omb.service.exception.UserSessionInvalidException"
                result="sessionInvalidError" />

        </global-exception-mappings>

    </package>

    <package name="omb" extends="default" namespace="/omb">
        <action name="doAction.do" class="myAction" method="{1}">
            <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
                <param name="namespace">/omb</param>
                <param name="actionName">displayResult</param>
            </result>
            <result name="error" type="redirectAction">
                <param name="namespace">/error</param>
                <param name="actionName">displayError</param>
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**`web.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

    <display-name>MyApplication</display-name>
    <description>Application OMB</description>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:applicationContext.xml,
            classpath:applicationContext-web.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.tiles.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-defs.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>struts.ajax.debug</param-name>
        <param-value>${struts.ajax.debug}</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Acegi Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Acegi Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Java Melody filter mapping -->   
    <filter-mapping>     
          <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>     
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>   
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.omb.listener.ApplicationListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!--  listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener-->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**`MyAction.java`:**

```
package com.omb.actions;

@Repository("myAction")
@Scope("session")
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {

    @Qualifier("myService")
    private MyService myService;

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        myService.callMethode();
        return SUCCESS;
    }


    public MyService getMyService() {
        return this.myService;
    }

    public void setMyService(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Spring plugin, so the integration of struts with spring is successful the `objectFactory` of struts is delegating the building of the action to spring, so it could use to inject dependencies from the spring application context. But the action bean is managed by the struts container, so it keep a possibility of DI internally. If you want to completely delegate the bean to be managed by spring you should configure action beans in application context and in action configuration replace the class references to the spring ids.

In the `applicationContext.xml` place

```
<!--<context:annotation-config/>-->
<context:component-scan base-package="your.base.package"/>
```

to point the spring to scan for beans in the package hierarchy.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. But it only works if I define my action in the applicationContext.xml file. Id'like to the define it with annotations.

Comment: Place Component annotations on beans and enable packages scan by spring to load annotated classes.

Comment: Excuse me can you show me a sample code because I think that's what I did. Unless there was an error in the code I posted above. Thank you.

Comment: Error in the code, remove `classpath:applicationContext-web.xml`

Comment: I found the solution ... I forgot to add <context:component-scan base-package="com.omb.actions" /> in the applicationContext.xml file!

Comment: Where did you find it in my answer?